# How to list available WM_CLASS options?

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I am running the command to get data on the active applications/windows of Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wmctrl -xlp | \
    grep "$(xprop -root | \
      grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | \
      head -1 | \
      awk '{print $5}' | \
      sed 's/,//' | \
      sed 's/^0x/0x0/')"
```

I get info on `WM_CLASS` in response.
For example: `google-chrome.Google-chrome`, `slack.Slack`, `Navigator.Firefox`, etc.

How may I get the list of all possible values that may come up for a user of the system?
If all possible values is not possible then at least most or some of them would be great.